# Creating animation on layout.addView android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

Is there a way to create an animation/transition for inserting a view into the layout?

For example

```
val layout = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linLayout)
layout.addView(someNewView)
```

I want to add view in the correct position without specifying the exact x and y in an animation like move from bottom outside the screen to its position

is there a way to do it?

thank you!